# Compilador não detecta funções signal

Tags: c

Boa noite!

Estudo engenharia informática e recentemente tenho programado em C devido a um projeto... Esse mesmo projeto usa duas bibliotecas (#include signal.h, #include signal.h). Usamos um servidor onde todos os alunos programam e usamos um programa chamado putty para se conectar a esse servidor.

O problema aparece quando uso um programa externo a esse servidor (ex. Visual Studios, codeblock, codelite) e quando tento compilar, dá me o erro de "implicit declariton of function" da **função kill** e ainda, em relação aos sinais, diz que os alarmes não estão declarados (ex. SIGKILL undeclared, first use in this function).

Comment: Certamente o servidor no qual você se conecta trata-se de um ambiente Unix/Linux.

Comment: Sim! então é por ai que vêm essas bibliotecas... Então posso eu criar numa máquina virtual esse ambiente linux e tentar reproduzir o código que pretendo?